# Local website cross-browser tester

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I found -using the search form- many free/payed tools to test online websites,

But do you know a GOOD one to test in local:

- IE 6/7/8/9
- FF's
- Opera's
- Chrome's

And that let's test the Javascript interface aswell (client side), not only screenshots

And if posible to combine with the different screen resolutions?

it doesn't matter if is a paying software, but if is Open, better;

Comment: while it does not answer your question, a possible solution is to try using something like dyndns to use the online tests to check your local machine.